# How to load incremental data using Pentaho's MongoDB input step?

Tags: mongodb, etl, pentaho, data-warehouse

I am using Pentaho DI (Spoon) to ETL about 700 million records of existing data from MongoDB to a MySQL warehouse, after which I will need to update the warehouse with about 100,000 new records that are added each day.

The problem is that each time I run the job after the initial load of 700m records, the 'MongoDB Input' step in Pentaho tries to read all of the mongo source data (i.e. the previous 700m plus the couple hundred thousand new records added each day) which takes ages. I only want it to read in data that it has not seen before, similar to AWS Glue Bookmarks, but can't seem to figure out how to do that. In other words I would like to do something like an incremental data read from the MongoDB source. Has anybody solved this issue before?

Comment: Maybe you can track the incremental data using the MongoDB [Change Streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/index.html).

Comment: Thanks @prasad_. I will take a look and see if that works.